# differences between onload() uses in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if there is a difference between those 2 differents way of using onload() function ? (time delay, order of execution etc.) or is it exactly the same ?

Thanks

1st way :

```
<iframe onload="frameload()" src="script.php" name="myFrame" id="myFrame"></iframe>

<script>



function frameload(){


            var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame'); 

            var innerDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

            document.write(innerDoc.getElementById('ele1').value);

        }

</script>
```

2nd way:

```
<iframe src="script.php" name="myFrame" id="myFrame"></iframe>

<script>

document.getElementById('myFrame').onload=function() {

            var iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame'); 

            var innerDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

            document.write(innerDoc.getElementById('ele1').value);


}

</script>
```

Comment: First approach will throw an error if javascript is disabled, that's the only difference. However, the second one is better practice. Scripts shouldn't be pushed into the markup, that leads to a lot of confusion because your presentation actually does something by itself and you don't see it quickly.

Comment: "First approach will throw an error if javascript is disabled" — What error?

Comment: @Quentin No error, you are right, thanks for that. I never used inline javascript in production code but was convinced it would at least display an error message because the code isn't allowed to run but is part of the markup. Sure enough I think this is weird behaviour to force disabled code into presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example the effect is the same.
Anyway, if you'd need to use `this` inside your function, in the first case `this` refers to the `Window` object, while in the second one it refers to the `iframe` DOM node.

Additionally, as other pointed out, inline JS code is bad for several reasons. In a nutshell, it's preferable to separate the JS from HTML to improve readability and caching (e.g. if the code is in a separate file).

Comment: In the case "script.php" would be in a other domain, without considering Same Origin Policy, would both my solutions still works ? i tried both those solutions on a CSRF challenge (root-me.org), only the 2nd solution worked...

Comment: actually they should both work, but as we said I see no advantages in using the first solution instead of the second one..

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no significant performance difference, however the 2nd approach helps you separate the concerns - markup (HTML) and functionality (JS).

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 should be identical.

It's nicer to add it via

```
.addEventListener("load", yourFunction);
```

If that's not possible in your case your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Lorenzo's answer and I would like to add that the second approach is a bit faster. Here are the results from firefox, please check the links I used a random link as a source for iframe:

First approach: http://screencast.com/t/esXo0jC4Qcx

Second approach: http://screencast.com/t/BlLmXcPtuZW

Answer (score -1):

ofcorz both are same.

standard coding style is the second one.
But some times we have to follow the first approach.

eg. if we have a textBox with same id *"txtStudentName"* in Create and Edit pages and have to autocomplete it only on create page. In such condition you can use first approach to autocomplete. Othewise the code will affect both textboxes by using a single js

Comment: You cannot use two elements with the same `id` in one HTML page. It is prohibited. `id` has to be unique.

Comment: @Anton i have mentioned it above that there are two different pages `Create` and `Edit` and Using same `.js` file in both pages :(

Comment: ok, I see. Still it is not an excuse for using `onload="frameload()"`. In the case you described another approach should be taken to ensure that the same JS file will not collide if it is used accross multiple pages. JS files are often bundled to a single cached file used across the whole domain. So if you use the same `id` on different pages (which is valid), make sure you do not use `document.getElementById` for that `id`.Use another way to select the proper HTML element - e.g. place HTML page of edit page inside `<div class="edit">` and create page inside `<div class="create">`.